# API to read, write and manipulate msword files

Tags: java, microsoft-word

I want to write some java code to read, write, edit and do other things with sets of Microsoft Word files (different Word versions). What is the best API for this, and how do I get started? P.S. I searched StackOverflow and found that this question has been asked before, but several years ago. I would like to know the best available API today. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't use it for a long time but [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) is still alive.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I am looking at now.